# NSDate to System.DateTime

Tags: ios, datetime, nsdate

I'm trying to call a web service from my iOS app.  The web service requires a System.DateTime value, but I'm using NSDate within the app.  How do I convert the NSDate to a System.DateTime objecct in iOS?

Comment: You need to clarify what a `System.DateTime` value looks like.

Comment: There is no such thing as `System.DateTime` on iOS... that only exists on Windows. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Going beyond Abhi's and rmaddy's comments, there's no such thing as a `System.DateTime` anywhere other than in .NET. Not in XML, not in JSON, not in Java, not in Objective-C. It's something Microsoft invented.

Comment: What you need to do is decide on a standard character date format (or a single number like seconds since some epoch) and convert to/from that.  Both Objective-C and .NET have good date conversion facilities if you work it through carefully.

Comment: Right, so I know that iOS doesn't have a System.DateTime.  But the WebService I'm using requires that as the data type to one of the inputs of the WebService

Comment: That's when you go and find a spec for System.DateTime.

Comment: Exactly.  Which is what I tried to find and when I couldn't, I came here to try to find an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  If I pass in a string to the Web Service formatted, correctly (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:000z) then it works